# SharePoint 2010 client object model, clear content type collection

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject, contenttype

I have an SP.ContentTypeCollection for a document library.  I'm trying to add a selected one from the site's content types.  I also need it to be the new DEFAULT content type for that library.

Thus, I've copied the document library's existing types to a list.  Then I want to clear the content types and add my new one FIRST so it becomes default.  Then I will add the others I copied.

PROBLEM: I can't find a way to delete one or all of the content types in the collection.

Help?  :-)  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete an element from SP.ContentTypeCollection list. This [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/8203/delete-the-list-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010-using-client.aspx) provides a code snippet to delete a content type by using client object model , but the code  doesn't check if the  content type that is being used as you cannot delete a content type that is being used.

The code snippet use the function [ContentType.DeleteObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.contenttype.deleteobject%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to delete a content type, please be aware of the exceptions in that MSDN link.